# How to hide the section that have no data from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, database

I am a newbie. I have the php code to print the data from database using rest api but the data is not complete. How do hide the I make the section that has no data?

Do I need to use if else logic?

```
<div class="cardbaru">
<div class="card">
<img class="a" src="<?php print_r( $result->result->test[0]->logo ); ?>" 
onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='images/test default logo.jpg';" 
alt="test Logo" >
<h2><?php print_r( $result->result->test[0]->name ); ?> </h2>
<p><?php print_r( $result->result->test[0]->ssmid ); ?></p>
<p><?php print_r( $result->result->test[0]->category ); ?></p>
<p class="test"><?php print_r( $result->result->test[0]->address ); ?>
</p>
<img class="c" src="<?php print_r( $result->result->test[0]->logo ); ?>" 
onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='images/test default logo.jpg';" 
alt="test Logo" >   
<h2><?php print_r( $result->result->test[0]->name ); ?> </h2>
<p><?php print_r( $result->result->test[0]->refererid ); ?></p>
<p><?php print_r( $result->result->test[0]->category ); ?></p>
 <img class="a" src="<?php print_r( $result->result->test[1]->logo ); ?>" 
 onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='images/test default logo.jpg';" 
 alt="test Logo" >
  <h2><?php print_r( $result->result->test[1]->name ); ?> </h2>
  <p><?php print_r( $result->result->test[1]->ssmid ); ?></p>
  <p><?php print_r( $result->result->test[1]->category ); ?></p>
  <p class="test"><?php print_r( $result->result->test[1]->address ); ?>
  </p>
 <img class="c" src="<?php print_r( $result->result->test[1]->logo ); ?
 >" 
  onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='images/test default logo.jpg';" 
  alt="test Logo" > 
  <h2><?php print_r( $result->result->test[1]->name ); ?> </h2>
  <p><?php print_r( $result->result->test[1]->refererid ); ?></p>
  <p><?php print_r( $result->result->test[1]->category ); ?></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: You can use if else statement on all or at the very top to check and display elements,

Comment: @syfer can you give me an example how I can apply in my code?

Comment: A quick search (even google) will give you a good working example but here is one `if ($t < "20") { echo "Have a good day!"; }`

Answer (score 0):

try the following here $result is the variable consisting the data you can also check if it exists or not using isset() function also

```html
<?php 
if(empty($result)==false)
{
echo "write code";
?>
//html code
<?php
}

?>
```